# Moving bluetooth pairing from one PC to another?

Tags: linux, bluetooth

I'd like to be able to move bluetooth pairing from one PC to another so the bluetooth device would automatically pair to the new PC. It appears that this is requires a few things:

- Moving the credentials (stored where?) from the first PC to the second
- Using Bluez's bdaddr to change the device address of the second PC to match the first PC

Has anyone done this before? The use would be a multi-device/multi-user kiosk where the logged in user would have their devices connected to without having to re-pair each time.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could do this as you describe by spoofing BDADDRs to match and copying the link keys.  On BlueZ/Ubuntu, link keys are stored in `/var/lib/bluetooth/<BD_ADDR>/linkkeys`

Comment: Is there anything else that would need to be done? Anything obvious that I'm missing here?